# creating one chart multi-timeframe with add-on indicators?

Tags: pine-script

Wanted to know if in pinescript, is it possible to create a One chart with multiframe plus a databox floating or fixed with additional addons such as vwap, BB,std,rsi, rsi,etc....linked to individual timeframe on the chart with data readout in the box??

looking to see if possible, new to programming

Comment: @vitruvius do you know anyone that can create this for me? or give me directions as to where I can look to create this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You can request data from different time frames with the [security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html?highlight=security) function.

Then you can display this data in a [table](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Tables.html?highlight=table).